# Converting Excel formula to PHP or MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, phprunner

I'm trying to convert an excel scoring program and this one formula is driving me nuts.  so this is the excel formula `=IF(AD4<AE4,AE4-AD4,0)` and I have been stumped for a little bit. I have looked at, and tried a few sample formulas for both PHP & MySQL, but I keep receiving syntax errors, unexpected if or else in the code.

So what the formula is checking to see if the elapsed time is under a set time, and if so, calculates the difference between the 2 fields and displays the outcome in time format hh:mm:ss.

This is the latest SQL query I tried:

```
Select *
       if (`Under Time`<`Speed Fault`,0) 
       else { (`Time Elapsed`-`Speed Fault`)} As Under Time 
from time_db
```

Comment: You can use the SQL `IF()` to accomplish the same thing: `SELECT *, IF(\`Under Time\` < \`Speed Fault\`, \`Time Elapsed\`-\`Speed Fault\`, 0) AS \`Under Time\` FROM time_db`.

Answer (score 0):

In sql , you can use `case` :

```
Select *,case when (UnderTime<SpeedFault) 
              then 0 
              else TimeElapsed - SpeedFault end As UnderTime 
from time_db
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
       GREATEST(`Time Elapsed`-`Speed Fault`, 0) AS `Under Time`
FROM time_db;
```